# How to pass data between 2 userControls WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, pass-data

I have 2 `UserControl` pages.
In one I have a `ListBox` and a "continue" `Button`.
I want to pass the list to another `UserControl` page after I click "continue" but i can't figure out how to do it (Just found examples for `Form` or `Window`).

I already found how to move to another page, but not how to pass the data in it.
Thanks!

This is my code:
The button in the first Xaml (I have there a `ListBox` named `lbOne`):

```
<Button x:Name="button" 
        Content="Continue"  
        Grid.Column="2"  
        Margin="81,0,0,-30"  
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.184,-1.455" 
        Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Style="{DynamicResource BaseButtonStyle2}"
        Click="button_Click"
        Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" 
        CommandParameter="/Pages/NextPage/nextPage.xaml"/>
```

And this is the list:

```
ObservableCollection<My_Data> list = new ObservableCollection<My_Data>();
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    list.Add(new My_Data("first", "explanation"));
    list.Add(new My_Data("second", "explanation"));
    list.Add(new My_Data("third", "explanation"));
    list.Add(new My_Data("forth", "explanation"));
    list.Add(new My_Data("fifth", "explanation"));

    lbOne.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Edit:
I will just be clear and say i want to share the data in the ListBox and not the ObservableCollection because i add more data to the listbox itself at the entire code (This way: `lbOne.Items.Insert(insertAtIndex, dragDropData);`)

Comment: The UserControls should bind to a shared view model in their DataContext. Search the web for the MVVM architecture pattern and the basics of WPF data binding.

Comment: I will try to find something about it, thanks.

Comment: It is always good to use Patterns like MVVM , but if you want other solutions  Link1 : https://wpfglue.wordpress.com/tag/gotopage/  Link2: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/community/thread/3496/ribbon-tab-that-supports-icheckablecommandpar